# Looping through a series of web elements of common class name

Tags: python, selenium

I'am writing a code to do the following using python and selenium:

1.go to google maps and search London Restaurants

2.click on first restaurant to view details and then go back to previous page and click the next restaurant (i, i+1, i+2 etc...)

3. Note all restaurant click pages have common class names (being 'section-result')

however when I'am running the code, for some reason, driver is not clicking on the restaurant to go to the details page.

I have tried the following code, which also was suggested in another forum post for this problem. However so far unsuccessfully.

also i have tried to do a for loop which i have also included in the code section as (option 2)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import random
import time
import pandas as pd
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/users/usr/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")


UrlA = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/"
UrlB= "London"
UrlC="Restaurant"
UrlD= UrlA + UrlB + '+' + UrlC
driver.get("http://www.google.com/ncr") #to load page in english language
driver.get(UrlD)



time.sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('section-result')
```

Option 1:

```
for i in elements:
    i.click()
    driver.back()
```

Option 2:

```
for i in range (1,20):
    elements[i].click
    driver.back
```

the code line (i dot click) is not responding and instead its going back to previous page. Please advise the correct modification for the code

Comment: Try using explicit wait before starting the loop. `EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(elements)`

Comment: thanks but this did not help. when i try element[1].click, the software works but when i do option 1 or 2 it doesnt work. please help.

Comment: try using `i.sendkeys(Keys.ENTER)` or some other method of clicking

Comment: didnt work. any other suggestions?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Option 1 error: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.70)
this error is because it goes back to previous page and hence element is not there     ---Option 2 No error, keeps scrolling to the bottom of restaurant options and then clicks on last option then code ends with exit code 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201620/discussion-between-pratik-and-the-oracle).

Comment: for option you suggested :WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendkeys'